# How do I ensure that a layout update has occurred?

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, layout, actualwidth

I have a UserControl with a dependency property called `ItemsSource`. When the property is changed, I need to calculate the size of various elements. To do this, I have to access the UserControl's `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties.

The problem is, if an object is assigned to `ItemsSource` before a layout update has occurred, `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` are 0.

How can I ensure that a layout update occurs before responding to the property changed event while still allowing the property to be changed before a layout update has occurred?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized later that I don't actually need to rebuild the rows and columns every time my data source changes. Instead, I handle the `SizeChanged` event on my UserControl and perform the size calculations there. The event appears to fire when the control is first displayed, so it has a chance to make the initial calculations without any extra effort.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for - [UpdateLayout()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout%28VS.95%29.aspx)

This is a function which is defined on UIElement, however frequent use is not recommended as it will cause a layout pass.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have any effect. ActualWidth and ActualHeight are still 0.

Comment: Before calling `element.UpdateLayout()` you need to a `element.Measure(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PostiveInfinity)` and then a `element.Arrange(element.DesiredSize)`.